# C# check multiple client connections

Tags: c#, for-loop, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am currently developing a one-to-many relationship between one server and many clients.
Everytime a client connects I append to the client list: `clientList.Add(client);`

I wrote the following code to check the "pulse" of the client connection as to see if the client is still connected and currently updating the `toolStripStatusLabel1`

This seems to work well when checking one connection and in addition, I added the exception `cleanup()` when trying to send data so that it should check at all scenarios(Feel free to give your opinion).

My question now is, how do I check the connection from multiple clients?

Please find below the reference code:

```
private void StartListen()
        {
            //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
            tcpListener.Start();
            
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
            int counter = 0;
            appStatus = 0;

            
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    counter++;
                    clientList.Add(client);
                    
                    
                    IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
                    //Updating status of connection
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from " + IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());
                    appStatus = 1;
                    
                    th_outPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { outPutStream(client); });
                    th_outPutStream.Start();
                    th_inPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { inPutStream(client); });
                    th_inPutStream.Start();
                    th_checkConnection = new Thread(checkConnection);
                    th_checkConnection.Start();

                    
                    
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    Cleanup();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
    private void checkConnection()
    {
        bool status = true;
        while (status == true)
        {
            status = IsConnected();
            if (status == true) 
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //Wait 3 seconds then try again
            }
            else
            {
                Cleanup();
            }
            
        }

    }
```

---

```
private bool IsConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                return !(client.Client.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && client.Client.Available == 0);
            }
            catch (SocketException) { Cleanup(); return false; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by simply creating a forloop for each client in my client list:

```
private void checkConnection()
        {
            bool status = true;
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < clientList.Count; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(clientList.Count);
                    status = IsConnected(i);
                    if (status == true)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Cleanup(i);
                    }

                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //Wait 3 seconds then try again
            }
        }
```

---

```
        private bool IsConnected(int i)
        {
            try
            {
                return !(clientList[i].Client.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && clientList[i].Client.Available == 0);
            }
            catch (SocketException) { Cleanup_dep(); return false; }
        }
```